# duplicating a chatbox using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a program that when a user clicked a name from the list of his friends, a chat box will pop up, and i want my chat box to be as many as the user that he clicked. however my problem is, I can only make a single chatbox, how will i be able to make a multiple chatbox and have a unique ID of it?

here is my html and php:

chat lists:

```
   <id = "chat_lists">
   //my friend names goes here. 

   //you can ignore this codes, but i'll put this for
     those people who want to see what's happening.

    //selects all the friends of this user

     if($run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query_select))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
        {
            $chat_name = $row['full_name'];
            $seen = $row['seen'];
            $user_id = $row['users_id'];

            if($seen == 'online')
            {
                $color = "green";
            }
            else
            {
                $color = "gray";
            }
            if($user_id !=$get_user)
            {
                 echo "<div id = $user_id class = 'chat_div'><a class = 'chat_name'>".$chat_name."</a>"."<a class = 'seen' style = 'color:$color'>".$seen."</a></div>".'<br/>';
            }
        }
    }


   </div>
```

chat box:

```
<div id = "chat_box">
        <div id = "header"><a id = "close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></div>
        <div id = "message_area">
        <ul id = "updated_text">
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "bottom">
        <textarea id="textArea" name = "message" placeholder="Send a message.."></textarea>
        <input type = "submit" value = "SEND" id = "send_button">
        </div>
</div>
```

jquery and ajax:

```
$('.chat_div').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); // gets the id of the selected user
        $('#chat_box').show(); // shows the chat box
        $('#updated_text').text(''); //clears the data
        $.ajax({
                url: 'plugins/get_chatmate_id.php',
                data: {id:id},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var d = $('#message_area');
                    d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight")); // scrolls down the div
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: you need to use unique id's for all checkboxes. for example: chat_box_[id of the user here], and then `$('#chat_box_' + id).show();`. In this case you need to create the chat boxes on fly in your chat_div.click function.

Comment: you don't need to use ID's at all. There are lots of ways to use common classes with traverses and/or indexing and/or storing object references to do what is needed

Comment: but i will use ajax to that chatbox, and select all the conversation between those 2 users, how will i identify which chatbox i'm referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t17930y/)
Of course, this is just a simple solution, but i hope, it will help you.
Every time, when a new chatbox is open, incrase the value of the `openedCheckboxes` hidden value. You can use a global variable for that also. Then you can positioning the chatboxes. Add them a `position: absolute` and based on opened checkboxes, you can calculate the position of them.

The HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_friend" data-id="1">Friend 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_friend" data-id="2">Friend 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="chat_friend" data-id="287">Friend 287</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="openedChatBoxes" value="0" />

<div class="chatBoxHolder"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
    div.chatBox {width: 150px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #f00;} 
</style>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.chat_friend').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var userId = $(this).data('id');
            var divToShow = '<div class="chatBox" data-id="chat_box_' + userId + '" id="chat_box_' + userId + '"><div>Your chat box code here with user '+ userId + '</div><div><a href="#" class="close">close</a></div></div>';
            $('.chatBoxHolder').append(divToShow);
            /*
             * Here you can do what you want with ajax
             $.ajax({
             url: 'plugins/get_chatmate_id.php',
             data: {id: userId},
             success: function(data) {
             //$('#chat_box_' + userId); //At here, you can access your chat_box like this, but remember, this is a live element, so use 'on' function to manilulate
             var d = $('#message_area');
             d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight")); // scrolls down the div
             }
             });
             */
        });

        $('.chatBoxHolder').on('click', '.close', function() {
            $(this).closest('.chatBox').remove();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I get the idea sir, I'll try if i can implement this in my program. thanks :)